# Generate 1 GB file containing 4 columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory, size

I want to generate a file in python with following specifications:

Column 1: Sno
Column 2: Should be randomly assigned as numbers 1-10
Column 3-Column4: Should be random characters of length 1-32

I want this file to be over 1 GB of size. I am currently using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string
from random import choices
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(50000000,1)),
                    columns=['integer1'])

df['String1']= ["".join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=random.randint(1,32))) for _ in range(50000000)]
df['String2']= ["".join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=random.randint(1,32))) for _ in range(50000000)]
```

But this code is really slow and taking so much time. Is there a more efficient way of doing it ?

I also find the row which has the highest number of vowels considering the string columns.

Also, is there a way not to generate 50 million (rows as seen in the code) but still make the size upto 1 GB, something like an "Anti-Compression".

Thanks

Comment: What is `id_generator` used for?

Comment: oops sorry, thats redundant. I will remove it.

Comment: Why are you trying to make a giant file?

Comment: The more efficient way is not to do it in Python. 1. While numpy is fast, bridging is slow, and you have to bridge every time you touch strings. 2. numpy relies on doing things in batches to reduce number of times you need to bridge; so checking as you go how many items you need is not going to work. This would be trivial (and fast) to do in C: generate each row, add its length to sum, print it out, break loop if sum over 1G.

Comment: Its a challenge with my friend, which I completed but was trying to find an efficient way to do it

Comment: @Amadan this calls numpy once with a fully defined output shape.

Comment: @roganjosh: You're right, I wasn't paying attention. It's even worse - the last two columns are all in Python. The last two lines construct 50000000 list objects, around 825000000 int objects and 50000000 string objects, each. That's 1850000000 object instantiations.

Comment: why not incorporate some bash into your approach?

Comment: @aws_apprentice I did understand, I am sorry. I am not a very good coder

Comment: are you on a unix machine or windows

Comment: @aws_apprentice I am on windows

Comment: then you’ll have to look up a windows approach and use @Amadan advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think it will have fewer memory allocations so hopefully a bit quicker (took ~ 300s for me). You can do it quicker just by streaming data straight to a file, no real need to use Pandas, but I used it here as you started with it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string
from random import choices
from string import ascii_lowercase

size = 50000000

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(size,1)),
                    columns=['integer1'])

df['String1']= pd.util.testing.rands_array(32, size)
df['String1'] = df['String1'].apply(lambda x: x[0:random.randint(0,32)])
df['String2']= pd.util.testing.rands_array(32, size)
df['String2'] = df['String2'].apply(lambda x: x[0:random.randint(0,32)])

df.head()
```

### Alternatively, just going straight to file which will use less memory:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "w")

for i in range(0,30000000):
    f.write("{},{},{}\n".format(random.randint(0,10), ''.join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=random.randint(1,32))), ''.join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=random.randint(1,32)))))
    if i % 50000 == 0:
        f.flush()

f.close()
```